# Understanding equality in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

I have some `item`s which I fetch from Realm:

```
let items = realm.objects(ShoppingListItem.self)
print("\(items.count) items") // 10 items
```

Each `item` has a `subdepartment`, and each `subdepartment` has a `department`:

```
let departments = items.flatMap({ $0.product?.subdepartment?.department })
print("\(departments.count) departments") // 10 departments
```

My goal is to find the unique `Department` objects from this list. The expected result is 4. My standard approach here is to use `Set`:

```
let uniqueDepartments1 = Set(departments)
print("\(uniqueDepartments1.count) unique departments via Set") // 9 unique departments via Set - but changes every time!?
```

I figure there must be something I'm missing related to the way Realm treats equality. But to check, I also attempt to get the unique departments via enumeration:

```
var uniqueDepartments2 = [Department]()
for department in departments {
    if uniqueDepartments2.contains(department) {
        continue
    }
    uniqueDepartments2.append(department)
}
print("\(uniqueDepartments2.count) unique departments via enumeration") // 4 unique departments via enumeration
```

This is indeed the expected result.

Why doesn't `Set` work here as I expected it to? And why is the count changing each time I run it?

**Edit 2/27**

Here are the models in play:

```
class ShoppingListItem: Object {
    dynamic var product: Product?

    convenience init(ingredient: Ingredient) {
        self.init()

        self.product = ingredient.product
    }
}

class Product: Object {
    dynamic var productID, subdepartmentID, title: String?
    dynamic var subdepartment: Subdepartment?
}

class Department: Object {
    dynamic var departmentID, title: String?
}

class Subdepartment: Object {
    dynamic var subdepartmentID, departmentID, title: String?
    dynamic var department: Department?
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben. What's your definition of "unique" in this case? Realm `Object`s do override `isEquals:`, and our definition of equality is that two objects are equal iff they refer to the same underlying object in the same database. Even so, it's a bit surprising that the `Set` initializer doesn't seem to be behaving in the expected manner. Would you be willing to share your model definitions?

Comment: @AustinZ That's the implementation of `isEqual` I was expecting. Either way, I would think that the Set initializer and `contains` would ordinarily use the same implementation, whatever it is. I'm probably missing something else - yes, I'll add some model info shortly.

Comment: @AustinZ added some model info. Nothing too exotic I don't think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: in order for an `Object` subclass to be correctly hashable you must currently declare a property as the primary key.

`Set` is built on top of a hash table. This means it checks for the existence of a specific object by first computing the hash value of the object, mapping that hash value to a bucket within the hash table, and then checking each entry in that bucket for equality with the specified object.

The nature of this implementation means that for `Set` to work correctly on objects of a given type, both the `hashValue` property and `==` operator must obey specific rules. In particular, any two objects for which `==` returns `true` must return the same value from their `hashValue` property (the reverse is not required; it's completely valid for two unequal objects to have the same `hashValue`). Realm's implementation's of `hashValue` and `==` don't currently meet this criteria *unless* your class declares a property as the primary key. When no primary key is declared, `Object`'s default `hashValue` calculation defers to `-[NSObject hash]`, which simply returns the object's address in memory. Since `Object.==` allows two objects with different addresses to compare equal, this violates the relationship between `hashValue` and `==` I outlined above, leading to incorrect behavior when used with `Set` or as the key of a `Dictionary`. I've filed a [bug against Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4705) requesting that the behavior of `==` be fixed to be compatible with the value returned by the `hashValue` property.